# How to make my Flash Builder Application self adjusted to the screen?

Tags: android, flash-builder

I have problems doing the settings to allow my application to self-adjusted to the screen. I am currently doing an Android application. However, doing a coding of applicationDPI :160 does not helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a Flex mobile project, the default project created through the Wizard will automatically adjust to fit your screen size. Simply create a new Flex mobile project, give it a name, and select the desired platforms (Android). Create a couple debug configurations with various screen sizes. Without any code or settings changes at all, it should work on each configuration.

Comment: Is there any coding to center and resize the screen for differents mobile? I'm still learning, & it's quite urgent. I need help asap.